How to buy newly launch tokens from bsccan, that have insufficient liquidity?
When the contract address and supply of a token is created and got listed on bsccan before any other exchange the creator of the token tends to provide no liquidity for the token, which makes in impossible to buy maybe, because no swap is able to swap my BNB for that tokens and gives the same error "insufficient liquidity for this trade" no matter how much slippage i use and how much low quantity I want to buy, this is some serious and frustrating issue I am facing for quite a while, is there any genius that can help me figure this out and crack the code for me on how to buy such tokens.
extremely Greatful for your time to read this. GOD BLESS Y'LL

If the token creator provides no liquidity how do you expect the trade to go through?

bscscan, isn't an exchange, it's an explorer. You don't list tokens on bsc. When using an AMM you are swapping on a smart contract that needs to have liquidity to facilitate the trade. If a deployer hasn't deposited tp (seeded) a pool, there is not path to trade on.
